# For a regular Borel measure with infinite support, how to find a decreasing sequence of positive measure open sets?

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure, borel-measures

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $\mu$ be a regular Borel measure on $K$ with infinite support. How to find a decreasing sequence of open sets $\{V_{n}\}$ such that $\mu(V_{n}) > 0$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(V_{n}) = 0$?

If $(X, \tau)$ is a topological Hausdorff space and $\mu$ is a measure on $X$, then definition of support of a measure is $\{x \in X: x \in N_{x} \in \tau \implies \mu(N_{x})>0\}$.

I am sure that the regularity of $\mu$ plays a role in finding the above decreasing sequence, but I don't know how. Please provide hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $\{x\in supp (\mu): \mu (\{x\}) >0\}$. If this is infinite then
there exist $x_n$'s with $\mu (\{x_n\}) >0$ for all $n$ and $\sum \mu (\{x_n\}<\infty$. Hence, $\mu (\{x_n\})  \to 0$. By going to a subsequence we may suppose $\mu (\{x_n\}) <\frac 1 {2^{n}}$.  Now there exist open sets $U_n$ with  $\mu(U_n)<\mu (\{x_n\})+\frac 1 {2^{n}}$ and $x_n \in U_n$. Note that $\mu(U_n) >0$ for all $n$ because $x_n$ belongs to the support of $\mu$.  Take $V_n=\bigcup_{k\geq n} U_k$.

The case where $\{x\in supp (\mu): \mu (\{x\}) >0\}$ is a finite set is easier. Here there exists at least one point $x$ in the support with $\mu (\{x\})=0$. Can you finish?

Comment: I fail to see why the measure of the above constructed sequence V_{n} goes to zero as n tends to infinity. Can you please explain? Also, in the second finite case, for each n, by regularity of the measure, we can choose open sets U_{n} containing that support point x, whose measure is less than 1/2^n and then construct V_{n} as in the first case. But again, why would the measure of these V_{n}'s go to zero as n tends to infinity?

Comment: $\mu (V_n) \leq \sum_{k \geq n} \mu (U_k)\leq \sum_{k \geq n}<\sum_{k \geq n} (\frac 1 {2^{k}}+\frac 1 {2^{k}}) \to 0$. In the second  case you don't take the union. You take $V_n=U_1\cap U_2\cap... \cap U_n$. @Tom

Comment: Yes, I now understood the convergence of V_{n} to zero. Also, I understood why the V_{n}'s should be considered as the finite intersections in the second case. Since each of the U_{n}'s contain x, so does their finite intersections, which in turn are also open neighborhoods of x and hence the measure of these finite intersections are positive. Thank you for your help!